# Is it ok to use both Angular js and jQuery in the same project?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, compatibility

Im new to angularjs and whenever I use Jquery and angularjs some changes in made in scope variable not getting reflected in view. so I want to know whether angularjs is fully compatible with jQuery.

Comment: Not fully compatible but It uses most of the functions of jQuery library. Google about jQlite. But in my opinion you should do all the tricks in angular way.

Comment: Duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505230/is-this-good-practice-to-use-jquery-in-angular-js-project?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only place you should use Jquery together with Angular is in your directives. Angular already uses a jquery lite version here. So if you need functionality that jquery lite does not support, you could add jquery.

You can read about Angulars jquery lite here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

In some cases u might need to use a jquery plugin or do some tricky DOM manipulation. This is where jquery truly shines.

Personally I would try to avoid using jquery if possible :)

Comment: JQuery also shines at handling old browsers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Both frameworks are just two ways to realize the similar objectives. But, there is no  really compitability issues when you use both.

But, if you want to use angular, it will be -in long term- easier for you to hold your project within the boundaries of angularjs. Otherwise you will not utilize the both adequately.